# AIR – Google Maps API Security Sandbox Violation?

Tags: google-maps, flash, google-maps-api-3, air

i've just started using the Google Maps API for Flash (map_1_20.swc) for an AIR 2.5 application i'm building with Flash CS5.  everything loads and display fine in the ADL except that i'm receiving security sandbox violations:

```
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
SecurityDomain 'http://maps.googleapis.com/mapsapi/publicapi?
file=flashapi&url=http%3A%2F%2FgMyDomainName.com&key=ABQIAAAAKlbBGDLCUgZLtxxJ6-
Hi9RQ7KOBhSjQi3kzVUu2XaSyicmBCGxQz68ixtUMxnYSMDFuMNT0cJYPwjQ&sensor=false&v=1.20&fl
pub=&flh=17e8cb187dcf0488fac63df6b16432b7592443ee&flc=at&flcl=a0g30ufvvrvvtvvbo03' 
tried to access incompatible context 'app:/MapTest.swf'

//MyDomainName.com represents my domain registered with the API key
```

the security sandbox violation is thrown wheneven i mouse in or out of the infoWindow.

here's my code for the document class

```
package
{
import com.google.maps.LatLng;
import com.google.maps.InfoWindowOptions;
import com.google.maps.Map;
import com.google.maps.MapEvent;
import com.google.maps.MapType;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;

public class MapTest extends Sprite
{
public function MapTest()
    {
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

private function init(evt:Event):void
    {
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

    var map:Map = new Map();
    map.key = "ABQIAAAAKlbBGDLCUgZLtxxJ6-Hi9RQ7KOBhSjQi3kzVUu2XaSyicmBCGxQz68ixtUMxnYSMDFuMNT0cJYPwjQ";
    map.url = "http://MyDomainName.com"; //MyDomainName.com represents my domain registered with the API key
    map.sensor = "false";
    map.width = stage.stageWidth;
    map.height = stage.stageHeight;     
    map.alpha = 0.0;

    map.addEventListener(MapEvent.MAP_READY, mapReadyEventHandler);
    map.addEventListener(MapEvent.TILES_LOADED, tilesLoadedEventHandler);
    addChild(map);
    }

private function mapReadyEventHandler(evt:MapEvent):void
    {
    trace("Map Ready");
    evt.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MapEvent.MAP_READY, mapReadyEventHandler);
    evt.currentTarget.setCenter(new LatLng(45.53329,-73.67638), 11, MapType.NORMAL_MAP_TYPE);
    }

private function tilesLoadedEventHandler(evt:MapEvent):void
    {
    trace("Tiles Loaded");
    evt.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MapEvent.TILES_LOADED, tilesLoadedEventHandler);
    evt.currentTarget.alpha = 1.0; //Create Fade In Here (Tween)

    evt.currentTarget.openInfoWindow(evt.currentTarget.getCenter(), new InfoWindowOptions({title: "Test Title", content: "Test Content."}));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think you might not have a cross-domain issues.

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html